# spivak calculus ,conic sections explanation

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, conic-sections, plane-geometry

[image]

[image]
[image]

this is from the appendix 4 (the conic sections)in  spivak calculus book.

i spend the whole day tried to understand what spivak means in the third picture ("we can make things a lot ....."),but without any reslut.

so please can you explain what exactly he means ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spivaks Calculus. Conics Section. Change of coordinates system](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3500816/spivaks-calculus-conics-section-change-of-coordinates-system)

Comment: no,and at this moment i want  just  to understand the part of"" rotating everything around the vertical axis"

Comment: In this picture, the $z$-axis is the vertical axis and the $xy$-plane is determined by the horizontal axis — not necessarily the $x$-axis — and the line perpendicular to the “paper” pictured. This line is the intersection of $P$ and the $xy$-plane. So he’s rotated space around the $z$-axis to bring that line of intersection into the “out of the page” position.

Comment: However, I still didn't understand

Comment: "the line perpendicular to the “paper” pictured" i can't see or imagine this line,also i don't undrestand what you mean by "the z-axis to bring that line of intersection into the “out of the page” position"

Comment: I will give it one last try. The line of intersection of $P$ and the $xy$-plane is, in particular, perpendicular to the $z$-axis since it lies in the $xy$-plane. Pretend for a moment that it passes through the origin. Then you can rotate space around the $z$-axis (around the origin in the $xy$-plane) to move it to — say — the $y$-axis. If it does not pass through the origin, do the same thing with the unique line parallel to it and passing through the origin.

Comment: thank you so much,now i can see clearly what he means ,but i still don't know why we should do the rotation of the space

Comment: So that he can now work with algebra in the plane of that figure. Now maybe that post I linked will clarify that!

Comment: okey thank you so much sir

Answer (score 0):

Taking equation of cone and general plane as

$$ \dfrac{z^2}{x^2+y^2}= C^2 $$

and

$$ \dfrac{x}{a}+ \dfrac{y}{b}+ \dfrac{z}{c}=1$$
the orthogonal  projection of intersection on $x-y$ plane is a conic section whose principal axes are *not parallel* to  $x-y$ axes.

Let $ c \to \infty,~b =-ma~$ we have a single straight line projection parallel to the  $x-y$  plane of  ellipse or hyperbola section.

$$ y+ m x= m a $$

whose principal axes are *parallel* to  $x$ and $y$ axes.

If the intersection plane is rotated by $45^{\circ}$ around z-axis, then

$$ x^2+y^2-x y=1 $$

a typical conic section projection  given below is obtained,

[image]

but whose axes are not parallel to $x-y$ axes.

By *everything* Spivak means the cone and intersection plane *together*.. need to be  rotated about z-axis to bring about the alignment.

Comment: do you know a vedio that describe what exactly spivak say?

Comment: Not aware of that video.